# BigQuery with service account - Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, service-accounts

Is there any Java sample for accessing BigQuery service using a app-engine service account ? I do not want to use OAuth flow.

Answer (score 2):

The one liner to get a service account credentials:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;

import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(new String[] {SCOPE}))
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(P12_KEY))
    .build();
```

Where:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "15-uin9i5@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
P12_KEY = "path/to/private_key.p12"
TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"
JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory()
```

Once you have the credentials, you can build the BigQuery service and use it as with any other authentication method:

```
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;

bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(
    TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
    "BQ-ServAcc/so/0.1").setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

For example, to check a job:

```
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.Job;

while (true) {
  Job job = bigquery.jobs().get(projectId, jobId).execute();
  System.out.println(job.getStatus().toPrettyString());
  if (job.getStatus().getState().equals("DONE")) {
    if (job.getStatus().getErrorResult() != null)
      System.out.println(job.getStatus().getErrorResult().toPrettyString());
    System.out.println(job.getStatistics().toPrettyString());
    break;
  }
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```